# Android best practice to check user "login" in every activity

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity

in my app user needs to authenticate before he can start using the app..
I have this code in startupActivity

```
private boolean checkAuthentication() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(
            "com.simekadam.blindassistant", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getBoolean("logged", false);
}

private void processStartup(){
    Log.d(TAG, "processing startup");
    if (checkAuthentication()) {
        Intent startApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                BlindAssistantActivity.class);
        startActivity(startApp);
    } else {

        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);


    }
}
```

it just works but I need to check it propably in every activity (in onStart or onResume methods), but it would cause code duplications among all my activities. What is the best way how to do this? Can I create a masteractivity which will be extended with other activities?

thanks

Comment: Could not understand your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can create a master Activity and use "extends" to inherit from it, however I'd look into AppState if I were you.

You can create a class that extends the Application class. You can then use this for "global" variables and states.

Check out this webpage:
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state

Comment: yes..so the best way is to create login assert variable into the application class and check it in every activity..sounds good..thanks

Comment: Yeah exactly. It's how I handle log in within my applications. A boolean variable held in AppState that I check in every Activity.

But to answer your other question about having a "Master Activity", that's easily done through inheritance. Create a class that extends "Activity" as your master class, and then your sub classes extend the master class.

Answer (score 0):

What I do sometimes, I have my default MainActivity that always run initially.

Then in onCreate I have a check to decide which screen to present:

```
boolean isLoggedIn = checkUserStatus();
Intent intent = isLoggedIn ? new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class) 
                           : new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

`checkUserStatus()` is a simple function which get a boolean flag to determine if the user was logged in or not:

```
protected boolean checkUserStatus(){
    boolean isLoggedIn ;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    isLoggedIn = pref.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
    return isLoggedIn ;
}
```

then set the `boolean` to true or false :

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putInt("LAST_VERSION_CODE", BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
edit.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);// or false if you log out
edit.commit();
```